# Php password_verify not working after specially created page

Tags: php, html, css, hash, passwords

I'm trying to build a simple forum setup and I can't for the life of me get the *password_verify* function to work.
To test it I created this small website but it still doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Verify</title>

<?php
$password1 = $password2 = "";
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
        echo "TEST<br>";
        $password1=password_hash($_POST["name"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $password2=password_hash($_POST["name"], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        echo $password1."<br>".$password2."<br>";
        if(password_verify($password1,$password2)){
            echo "VERIFIED <br>";
        } else {
            echo "ERROR <br>";
        }
    }
?>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightgrey">
<div style="width:100%">
    <div style="width:60%; text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <br><br>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Password: <input type="text" name="name" maxlength=255>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone else encounted this problem or have I made a complete mess of things?

Comment: `if(password_verify($_POST["name"],$password1))` Just read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/it/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Nice, that fixed everything thanks!!